# How to change the background of the TV Studio Virtual Set?

Tags: gimp

I was wondering if it is possible to replace the violet city skyline that appears om the background of this nice TV Studio Virtual Set as shown in this picture:

[image: TV Virtual Set]

with the one I wanted:

[image: fountain]

Thank you for your feedback!

I use Gimp 2.10.30

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Yes it's entirely possible. What have you tried? What has failed? We expect users to at least make some effort here.  This isn't a tutorial on demand site. We can offer help and advice. Also note that we do not do free work here.

Comment: Yes, but very complicated given that the vertical panes are half transparent... Furthermore the lighting in the set implies that the outside is dark, and you are putting a well lit background so it will clash, and you may have to add shadows of semi-transparent panes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You would be wise to use duplicated layers  (of your original layer), to help focus on various parts of the design. Label each layer as the name of the tool you are using, as well as the area of the photo.  From that point, for each layer that represents a certain subject matter, consider using the **Foreground Select** tool or **Select by color** tool, with all its various panel options, to get the parts of original photo you want. That will only leave you re-designing that parts that have complex transparency, like the tall glass windows.  And finally, inserting your new background image, in the back.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a Photoshop user. Assuming that Gimp has a Quick Selection tool that is similar, I would select the background (cityscape) and delete it, then on a new layer bring the photo in. Hope this helps!

Comment: IMHO  a lot more complicated that you think... did you try something that you can show, even with PS?

Comment: Hi again, you're totally right. I did not see that the verticals were partially transparent. I've gotten rid of the purple background using a few different tools: Curvature pen tool and polygonal lasso tool, which is ideal for straight lines. I've also darkened the new background a little. The verticals will need (as far as I know, maybe there's a better solution) to be redrawn and have some transparency added to it. I also deleted the lower purple curved area under the verticals by accident, which can be added back if I needed to (but this is a quick demo). Lemme know your thoughts!

Comment: @xenoid: trying to upload the image I worked on but not seeing a way to do it. Maybe it's because today is the first time I'm posting to SE?

Comment: Normally you can just paste it in the text. Otherwise post on IMGUR and add the URL to your post. But your comment describes a more complicate process than your answer, so you may want to update the answer.

Comment: @xenoid: Thanks for the tip on IMGUR. Here is the link to the image I worked on yesterday: https://i.imgur.com/9GS85Px.jpg. 
Please see my earlier comment on which tools I used within Photoshop to get to this point.

Comment: The panes are left with the buildings showing through... when they should now have the new water jets and the trees. This is the hard part. Also, you have removed the ring at the base of the panes and left the axes so not only are they now hanging  a bit my miracle, but they have this purpose-less spike at the bottom.

Comment: My original intention was to do this really quick and to give some direction, not do the entire thing! LOL Yes, I did mention that I deleted the bottom ring, which can be easily brought back as I have the same layer for reference on a layer directly underneath. I'd like to hear some input from the original poster, Archean Eon, on if my info is helping any.